# Drag and drop Magnet.js + svg смена цвета

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такая тестовая страница
http://simvl.ru/light/test/construct_test.html
Картинка, что на ней в самом начале svg. При нажатии на кнопку добавить элемент появляется новая ( уже png ). Отрабатывается скрипт и теперь можно их перетаскивать.
Все картинки, которые добавляются - обычные png. С ними никаких проблем нет.
Но первая svg - она не перетаскивается, чего бы я не делал.
Все что я смог придумать, это засунуть ее в див, но при этом я должен нажимать на сам див для перетаскивания, а не на его содержимое.
Сама svg выглядит так для дальнейшей возможной перекраски оной.

```
<object class="magnet" width="200"
                height="300"
                type="image/svg+xml"
                data="/Users/Votanko/Desktop/bootstrap_new/images/tiles/a4-vertical.svg">
        </object>
```

Либо сама библиотека не может работать с svg, либо я что-то не понимаю.
Добавил стиль `style="pointer-events: none"` Все заработало.
Получил следующую проблему. Не могу перекрасить. `svgElement` массив определяется, но `setAttribute` не отрабатывает. Пробовал кучу вариаций (цвет, толщина линий) в консоли - толку нет.

```
var object2 = document.getElementsByClassName('123');
    var svgDocument = object2[0].contentDocument; //получаем svg элемент внутри object
    var svgElement = svgDocument.getElementsByClassName("st2"); //получаем любой элемент внутри svg
    
    for (i = 0; i < svgElement.length; i++) {
        svgElement[i].setAttribute("fill", "green");
    }
```

Comment: а почему нельзя вставить svg кодом то есть прямо в html ?

Comment: картинок много. Там что есть, это только основные. И я, если честно не уверен, что это сработает. Хотя попробовать стоит...

Comment: вы попробуйте и отпишитесь

Comment: Решил проблему стилем. Но, в итоге изменить цвет не могу)

Comment: так же через object ?

Comment: Да. Этот код, что я добавил везде советуют. Но сетАтрибут не отрабатывает, в консоли после ввода команды показывается undefind и все. Не понимаю.

Comment: `object2[0]` это что такое ? а то может быть вот так `object[0]` ?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('123'); - возвращает массив. 
[0] - первый элемент. Я все упростил для ясности ( убрал циклы и прочее )
В массиве всего один элемент. К нему и обращаюсь. svgElement - это уже массив из все элементов svg картинки. Картинка состоит из 4-5 квадратов. В цикле их перечисляю и изменяю им цвет ( изменение цвета не работает ) Причем в самой svg Есть стили этого класса st2 - и эти стили я могу править в самой svg - картинка меняется.

Comment: Кажется локализовал проблему. Убрал стили все в .svg картинке. На странице она начала отображаться полностью черной. 
Но при этом можно менять стили у него